# Use NoSQL in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, memcached, innodb, nosql

I've noticed MySQL could use Memcached NoSQL with InnoDB but I can't retrieve information about how to use it.

I want to use with PHP.

Are NoSQL queries standard?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17481866/using-mysql-5-6-memcache might be helpfull

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL and NoSQL: Help me to choose the right one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4419499/mysql-and-nosql-help-me-to-choose-the-right-one). Not fully duplicate, but could help you, it has many resources.

Comment: Thank you for the links, they was helpfull. It's not duplicated, but related. I've continued retrieving information.

Comment: Another useful article, comparing performance of native Memcached, Memcached interface to InnoDB, and SQL interface to InnoDB: [MySQL 5.6 InnoDB Memcached Plugin as a caching layer](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2013/03/29/mysql-5-6-innodb-memcached-plugin-as-a-caching-layer/)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, MySQL only support memcached with NoSQL since version 5.6. Today this version it's not update yet in linux repositories and must be manually installed, specially in servers, e.g. `MySQL --version` (ubuntu) is 5.5.38 ; (RedHat server) 5.1

You also must install *libevent-dev* e.g:

Still some hacks are needed, and you must install memcache interface plugin for MySQL located in `$MYSQL_HOME/share`.

I found a well explained post how to install and try it:
http://chipersoft.com/p/MySQL-via-Memcache/

Due to its young state, it's not for production servers.

Use it with PHP is easy because memcache is a native module in PHP when you have `php5-cli` and `php5-memcache` installed:

```
<?php
$memcache = new Memcache;
if (!$memcache->connect('localhost', 11211)) throw new Exception("Could not connect");

if (!$memcache->set('bar', 'John|Smith')) throw new Exception("Could not store value");

$memcache->get('@@aaa'); //switch containers
$result = $memcache->get('AA');

var_dump($result);
```

**Conclusion**, this method let you work with MySQL and NoSQL simultaneously. Memcache offers a quick, NoSQL way to retrieve and work with data in a well different manner than SQL.

Edit: Another useful link was this [post by Tony Darnell](http://scriptingmysql.wordpress.com/2014/05/01/use-mysql-to-store-nosql-and-sql-data-in-the-same-database-using-memcached-and-innodb/)